# diskutil command not found in OS X terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, disk-utility

I am using Mac OS X 10.6.4 and am struggling with the command:

```
diskutil
```

Whenever I type in diskutil the terminal says:

```
-bash: diskutil: command not found
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Can I install the diskutil script (probably by copying some *.sh to some destination and adding something to the bash.profile)?

Answer (score 5):

`diskutil` is a system administrator command. That's why it's not in the default search path for ordinary users.

The usual way to run it is to run `sudo diskutil`. The [`sudo`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) command runs a command as the system administrator (`root`). `sudo` searches for the command in a different search path (it sets the `PATH` environment variable to a diffent value before searching for the command name), which includes `/usr/sbin` where system administrator commands such as `diskutil` reside.

If you do want to run `diskutil` as your ordinary user, specify the full path: `/usr/sbin/diskutil`.

Comment: While this is almost true, there are a few things you can do as a non-root user, list partitions, view the information on a mount point, etc. Basically the same stuff you can do inside of Disk Utility without unlocking it. Anything that actually presents a risk to data on disk will require root privs.

Comment: Actually, this answer is wrong on a couple of counts: first, OS X keeps sudo is in /usr/bin, not sbin; second, /sbin and /usr/sbin *are* in the default PATH for standard users as well as admins.

Comment: OSX Mavericks, and /usr/sbin/diskutil isn't there.

Comment: @OrangeDog Oh, do you know where it is? I don't have access to any OSX machine. Is `diskutil` on the default path?

Comment: @GordonDavisson This answer claims nothing about where `sudo` is. Evidently `/usr/sbin` (which is where `diskutil` was in OSX at the time) wasn't in Maccaius's PATH; was `/usr/sbin` in the default PATH in 10.6.4?

Comment: I don't have a 10.6.4 system handy, but under both 10.6.8 and 10.9.2, the default PATH is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`, `diskutil` is in `/usr/sbin`, and `sudo` is in `/usr/bin`. So, both `sudo` and `diskutil` have been in the default PATH for a long time and are still there. Not sure why `diskutil` is missing on @OrangeDog's Mac...

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
/usr/sbin/diskutil
```

instead of just:

```
diskutil
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your PATH (echo $PATH).  diskutil is in /usr/sbin.  Add it to your path if it isn't already there.  If it is, then yes, diskutil is missing.  (/usr/sbin/diskutil is an executable itself, not a shell script.)

Comment: could you tell me then line to add to the bash.profile in order to include /sbin/ ?

Comment: /usr/sbin doesn't belong in your ordinary users path, see Giles' answer.